# Is there a french translation for Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space

I would like to play Endless Space in French. Is there any way to do it? I use Steam in French already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the red marked box endless space is supporting french but text only (i used french steam store because you asked for french)

[image]

If you're still not able to start your game in french, try the following

**Changing the language of individual games**

The language of many games can be changed independently from the Steam client language.

- Log into your Steam account
- Right click on a game from the Steam game library and choose Properties.
- Go to the Language tab
- Select the language you wish to use from the drop-down menu
- Click OK
- If the game supports the language you have selected, files for that language may need to be downloaded before you can play.

Source: [Steam How-To's](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8487-WSCN-4121)